# Selenium WebDriver - Not able to select value from dropddown, element is not visible

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Here is my code snippet.

Element is not selected from dropdown, i am getting error as element is not visible, so web driver is not able to interact

```
package pac.PraticeSeleniumProgramsWebDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class WorkingWithSelectBoxInWebDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","C:\\Users\\A081368\\AppData\\Local\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        WebDriver Driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        Driver.get("https://login.yahoo.com/");

        timeout(Driver);
        Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Create Account')]")).click();
        timeout(Driver);
        Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='first-name']")).sendKeys("Satish");
        Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='last-name']")).sendKeys("Ranjan");
        Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='user-name']")).sendKeys("satishranjanbit");
        Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys("shalini1");

        WebElement element = Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select [@id='country-code']"));
        System.out.println("pass");

        Select Dropdown = new Select(element);
        System.out.println("pass1");

        Dropdown.selectByIndex(10);
        System.out.println("pass2");


        Driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='mobile']")).sendKeys("08105002231");
        System.out.println("pass3");

        Driver.close();
        Driver.quit();

    }

    public static void timeout(WebDriver Driver) {
        Driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `select` element with `id="country-code"` is really *not visible*, see `display: none;`:

```
<select aria-invalid="false" id="country-code" name="mobileCountryCode" data="country-code-drop-down" corresponding-field-id="mobile" style="display: none;">...</select>
```

Instead, you need to click the `div` element with `id="selected-country-code-1"`:

```
WebElement dropdown = Driver.findElement(By.id("selected-country-code-1"));
dropdown.click();
```

This would open up the dropdown. Then, to choose an option:

```
WebElement options = Driver.findElement(By.id("country-codes-menu-1"));
options.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Antarctica")).click();
```

This would choose `Antarctica` country code from the dropdown (assuming this is what you were planning to choose from the dropdown).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to select value from dropdown and the error is " element is not visible".
Then you are not supposed to use select class methods .First you need to click on dropdown div tag,means you need to enable the options from dropdown to select the values .

```
 WebElement dropdown= Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div"));
dropdown.click();
WebElement dropdownValue= Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("dropdown value"));
dropdownValue.click();
```